# How Does the "validatedToken" Work in "ValidateToken()" Method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I'm trying to understand the code block below. Everything is fine until the third argument of the `tokenHandler.ValidateToken(...)` method which is `out SecurityToken validatedToken`.

I checked the docs but could not find out much about that last argument. How does it work?

And what happens to `tokenHandler.ValidateToken(...)`? we are not assigning its return value to anything it looks like it just stays there and idk.

Could you make these clear for me?

```
private void attachUserToContext(HttpContext context, IUserService userService, string token)
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

            var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
            var userId = int.Parse(jwtToken.Claims.First(x => x.Type == "id").Value);

            // attach user to context on successful jwt validation
            context.Items["User"] = userService.GetById(userId);
        }
        catch
        {
            // do nothing if jwt validation fails
            // user is not attached to context so request won't have access to secure routes
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `ValidateToken()` takes the received token as a String, validates the token according to the `TokenValidationParameters` and creates an object of type `SecurityToken`, which is returned via the out parameter.

In the next line this object is casted to the type `JwtSecurityToken`

```
var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
```

and then parsed

```
var userId = int.Parse(...)
```

to get the `userId` and finally the `HttpContext context`

get's populated

```
context.Items["User"] = userService.GetById(userId);
```

with the user information. If validation is successful, you have the user information available via the httpContext.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's a huge help!